# Postgres timestamp conversion is backwards

Tags: postgresql, timezone

The server is in EST, I'm storing a `timestamptz` as `lastlogin`.

It seems like the conversion from UTC to EST is happening backwards.

```sql
select lastlogin at time zone 'EST' as lastlogin from users where id = 1;
-- > 2021-01-13 18:56:28

select lastlogin at time zone 'UTC' as lastlogin from users where id = 1;
-- > 2021-01-13 13:56:28
```

If to convert from UTC to EST I subtract 5 hours, why is EST 5 hours in the future? It's as if converting to UTC actually gives me the EST time, and converting to EST gives me the UTC time.

But this works:

```
select NOW() at time zone 'EST', NOW() at time zone 'UTC';
-- > 2021-01-13 14:23:21 2021-01-13 19:23:21
```

EDIT:

I found out that doing two conversions seems to work:

```
select lastlogin at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'EST' as lastlogin from users where id = 1;
-- > 2021-01-13 13:56:28
```

This is shown on [Popsql How to Convert UTC to Local Time Zone in PostgreSQL](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-convert-utc-to-local-time-zone-in-postgresql). Is it that the first `at time zone` will set the time zone for the time, while the second will actually do the conversion?

Comment: What is value of  `select lastlogin from users where id = 1;`?

Comment: It is `2021-01-13 18:56:28`

Comment: Glad you found an answer, but a word of caution. Don't use EST for the timezone; it is a time zone abbreviation. Instead use the full timezone name; either US/Eastern or America/New York, or other with offset -05:00 - there are 34*** of them). This is because the full name automatically adjusts for daylight savings while the abbreviation does not.  ***  select * from pg_timezone_names where abbrev = 'EST';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

First off, apparently that timestamp may not be a `timestamptz`. DBeaver says it is when I look at the table columns, but reports `timestamp` if I query it. Pgcli also says it is a `timestamp`.

That said, I found in the postgresql docs [9.9.3 AT TIME ZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) that:

> The AT TIME ZONE operator **converts time stamp without time zone to/from time stamp with time zone**, and time with time zone values **to different time zones**.

The explanation in my question's edit was correct. `AT TIME ZONE` on a `timestamp` will set the time's time zone to whatever you specify, then the second `AT TIME ZONE` will convert it.

Comment: In `psql` what does `\d user` show for lastlogin. I'm guessing it is `timestamptz`.

Comment: Well, I've noticed across two of our dbs lastlogin is different, one is `timestamptz` and the other `timestamp`. That's where I was getting confused. The ones in this example were `timestamp`.

Comment: See my answer for further explanation. If nothing else you found out why  `timestamptz` is better option then `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing and why it is important to store timestamp values in `timestamptz`:

```
set timezone = 'US/Eastern';

test(5432)=> \d ts_test 
                         Table "public.ts_test"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 ts_tz    | timestamp with time zone    |           |          | 
 ts       | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 ts_txt   | character varying           |           |          | 
 time_fld | time without time zone      |           |          | 

-- A timestamptz field always stores the value as UTC. A timestamp field is stored -- as a naive value. In below the timestamptz value is rotated to EST as that what -- the timezone is set to. The timestamp is also displayed in EST but with no time -- zone value, so naive.

select ts_tz, ts from ts_test ;
             ts_tz              |             ts             
--------------------------------+----------------------------
 01/14/2021 11:37:13.217229 EST | 01/14/2021 11:37:13.217229

-- Here the time zone is being explicitly set and both values are the same as 
-- timezone = 'EST'. The formally naive value does pick up a time zone designation -- per the docs "timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE zone Return Type --timestamp with time -- zone"

select ts_tz AT TIME ZONE 'EST', ts AT TIME ZONE 'EST' from ts_test;
          timezone          |            timezone            
----------------------------+--------------------------------
 01/14/2021 11:37:13.217229 | 01/14/2021 11:37:13.217229 EST

-- Here the the timestamptz value correctly gets rotated to UTC. The timestamp 
-- value gets set to UTC then gets rotated back to EST

 select ts_tz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' from ts_test;
          timezone          |            timezone            
----------------------------+--------------------------------
 01/14/2021 16:37:13.217229 | 01/14/2021 06:37:13.217229 EST
```