# how do I get the time zone name from a postgres timestamptz?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I bI am generating a materialized view in Postgres and one of the columns will contain a timestamptz that is the beginning of the month.   A regular
select date_trunc('month', t.starttime)
yields the start of the month in the time zone of the system that created or refreshed the materialized view.
I want to be able to specify the time zone for the start of the month to be in.
I can specify the timezone but I have to use a literal string.  Instead I'd like to use the value stored in a table.
This returns the value I want with the first of the month stored as midnight in Chicago:

```
select (date_trunc('month', t.tstzcol) at time zone 'America/Chicago')::timestamptz;
```

But I want want to replace 'America/Chicago'  with the time zone name of t.tstzcol.
I tried using `extract(timezone from t.tstzcol)` but  that returns an integer which doesn't work with `at time zone`

How can I force date_trunc to return a timestamptz in the desired time zone instead of the local timezone?

Comment: There is no time zone stored in the table.  From [Date/time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) read section *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps*. Actually that is not quite true, the timestamp is stored as UTC.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The timestamptz column type does seem to store the timezone offset with the time value or at least, in creating the materialized view, it sets the time value to midnight in the specified time zone (even if it only stored it in UTC, it will adjust the hours)

Comment: No it doesn't. Read the link I posted earlier.

Comment: Here are two of my answers that explain further: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708601/postgres-timestamp-conversion-is-backwards/65723450#65723450 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212229/postgres-date-time-is-automatically-converted/70237477#70237477

Answer (score 0):

A PostgreSQL `timestamp with time zone` does not contain a time zone. Rather, the value is stored in the database as the number of microseconds since `2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. The time zone offset that you see is calculated based on the current setting of `timezone` when you convert the value to a string.

You will have to store the time zone in a second column.